# Logstash - Pipeline has terminated

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am learning the ELK stack. At this time, I have Elasticsearch and Kibana setup on an AWS instance. I am successfully writing docs to an Elasticsearch index on that index via a Java console app I've written. I can see those logs in Kibana. Now, I want to see those logs input into Logstash on a different machine.

In an attempt to do this, I've installed Logstash. I added the following configuration:

**logstash.conf**

```
input { 
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "https://<aws-instance>.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243"
    user => "<myUsername>"
    password => "<myPassword>"
    index => "<myIndexName>"
    query => '{ "query": { "match": { "statuscode": 200 } }, "sort": [ "_doc" ] }'
  }
}
output {
  stdout { }
}
```

When I start Logstash from a console window, I'm expecting to see logs pushed to my Elasticsearch index appear. Instead, I see:

```
Sending Logstash logs to C:/Temporary/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[...][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[...][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.4.2"}
[...][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[...][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x13bbcec sleep>"}
[...][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[...][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[...][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline has terminated {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x13bbcec run>"}
```

I don't understand this. Why would the "pipeline" terminate? At this point, I don't understand if the issue is with Logstash or connecting to my Elasticsearch index. In either case, I have no idea. I also tried running with the `trace` log level. Unfortunately, I didn't learn anything from those additional logs. There are no ERROR messages. After the initialization of the Elasticsearch input plugin, I simply see:

```
[...][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.elasticsearch] Closing {:plugin=>"LogStash::Inputs::Elasticsearch"}
```

I don't know why it would close though.

Comment: Looks like logstash reads pipeline config from the wrong file. You should put your pipeline configs in this directory `/etc/logstash/conf.d/` by default logstash reads pipeline configs from `conf.d` folder.

Comment: @MichaelDz I'm running logstash on Windows, so `/etc/` isn't natively available. Still, I do believe that logstash is using the correct config file because otherwise, I don't think the `logstash.inputs.elasticsearch` `DEBUG` message would be shown.

Comment: Where is your pipeline config file stored and how do you start logstash?

Comment: I followed the instructions for Logstash setup. My config file is in the Logstash install directory. That directory has a directory called "bin", which includes the executable. To run Logstash, I enter `bin\logstash –f logstash.conf` from the command-line.

Comment: Use absolute path instead. And run elasticsearch query manually to see if it actually returns anything.

Comment: @MichaelDz I used absolute paths and received the same result. The elasticsearch query runs fine.

Comment: @MichaelDz Figured it out. The `schedule` attribute on the elasticsearch input was missing.